# Problem with cloth physics

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

I want to create a small animation of a cloth covering a car and then getting pulled off the car.

So I was thinking about making 2 simulations.

The first one would be the cloth falling on the top of the car and the second would be the actual animation of the cloth being pulled off the car (I was thinking about pinning some vertexes and parenting some bones that I would animate moving)

[image]

I stuck at the first part as you wan see and I am having some trouble in some areas with weird artifacts.

Here is a photo of the physics settings from the hood object. Everything is default settings 
[image]

I attached a blend file with the simulations appended from the original file

Also, the original file has a level 7 of subsurface but the uploaded has a level of 3, if your computer can handle it please add it to 7.

[image]

Comment: there is no car in the uploaded file. there is only a box and a plane.

Comment: Yes I know. I am not allowed to upload the car.
Is it possible to solve the problem with only a cube?

Comment: with level 3 of subdivision there is not problem. Are you sure you need to go with sub div of 7? it's really massive

Comment: Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Hello again! Here the the cloth with level 3 sub https://imgur.com/KavMS2f . It looks bad and I am not sure whats the problem